# Windows 7 - WLAN disconnects in fixed intervals

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I am using Windows 7 on my work machine and am facing some issues with my WLAN. It seems to disconnect every +- 40 seconds and then automatically reconnects.  This can go on for hours.

At first I thought this might be an issue with the signal strength, but then I left the dialog with the networks open during a disconnect to see my network listed with 4/5 signal strength. I can use the network on other machines in the same room without problems.

Comment: [Is Windows 32-bit or 64-bit?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827218/en-us) What's the wireless device exact model? Which driver version are you currently using?

Comment: one thing to quick check, look in the device manager , which will normally update when a device changes , and see if the device itself is dropping.   Another oddity set your power profile (temporarily) to never sleep anything including the screen.  <- 2 completly different things and not real likely but easy to check.